# Checking condition for each line in CSV

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Say I have a sample csv file like this:

```
phonemes,graphemes
W IY K D EY,w ee k d ay
T EH K S T,t e x _ t
Y UW,ewe _
SH UW T,chu te
SH UW T,chu te
SH UW T,chu te !
SX AH K,s u ck
```

I want to check a specific condition for each line. When I am trying to iterate through each line, when the element of one line meets the condition I want to increment my counter by 1 and continue to check for the next line instead of checking all elements in that particular line.

I believe this is similar to lazy evaluation? But I cannot figure out a way to complete this task.

My code for evaluating:

```
for p, g in reader:
        phonemes = p.split()
        graphemes = g.split()
        if (len(phonemes) == len(graphemes) and
            all(p in valid_pset for p in phonemes) and
            all(g in valid_gset for g in graphemes)):

            valid_row += 1
            p_count += len(phonemes)
            g_count += len(graphemes)
        else:
            invalid_row += 1
```

So with this code it will evaluate each element in a single line and every time it meets the requirement my `valid_row` or`invalid_row` will increment by **1**.

Which is not what I intend to do... 
I would like to know is there a way that I can simply evaluate, increment, and go to the next line to keep doing the same thing until the end of file?

Edit: when checking if it is valid I need all of the elements in that line to meet the correct requirement. And what would be a concise way to accomplish that(By checking all the characters in a line are valid, increment the valid counter by **1** )

Edit: I suppose when I hit a invalid character I can increment the counter and break from the inside loop and get to the next line then re-enter the loop? Or is there some quicker ways?

edit:

> AA
>   AE
>   AH
>   AO
>   AW
>   AY
>   B
>   CH
>   D
>   DH
>   EH
>   ER
>   EY
>   F
>   G
>   HH
>   IH
>   IY
>   JH
>   K
>   L
>   M
>   N
>   NG
>   OW
>   OY
>   P
>   R
>   S
>   SH
>   T
>   TH
>   UH
>   UW
>   V
>   W
>   Y
>   Z
>   ZH

This is a text file contain all the valid phonemes.(Which I have already added to a valid_pset)

And the valid graphemes is this:(Added to a valid_pset)

```
valid_graphemes = 
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 
 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '_'})
```

So when checking the sample file for example. The invalid rows should be **4**
But my code fails to do so.

**EDIT**: It seems like I may have found a way to do this. But one last thing that is keeping me from getting the correct answer is that how do I check for every element in a line that is in the text file? More specifically:

For `ee` I want to check both "e" in this "word" is in the valid_set. Meaning as long as both single "e" is in the set then `ee` should be valid. Any help on that?

Comment: It seems like what you have should be doing what you want it to do. Can you clarify what it's doing that you think is wrong?

Comment: What is the condition you are checking for? `all()` short circuits and the `and` short circuits, so if any condition is False it will immediately drop to the `else`.

Comment: I will edit the question sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** I modified the code in concert with the changed you made to the OP:

I ran this code, and it seems to work. It gave me one valid row, with explanations:

```
import csv

valid_pset = set("""
    AA AE AH AO AW AY B CH D DH EH ER EY F G HH IH IY
    JH K L M N NG OW OY P R S SH T TH UH UW V W Y Z ZH
    """.strip().split())
valid_gset = set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_")

valid_row = 0
invalid_row = 0
p_count = 0
g_count = 0

with open('test.csv','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    # Skip headers
    next(reader)
    try:
        line = 1
        for p,g in reader:
            phonemes = p.split()
            graphemes = g.split()
            line += 1

            valid = True
            if len(phonemes) != len(graphemes):
                print("Line {}: Number of phonemes and graphemes differ.".format(line))
                valid = False

            bad_p = [p for p in phonemes if p not in valid_pset]
            if bad_p:
                print("Line {}: Invalid phonemes {}".format(line, bad_p))
                valid = False

            graphemes = list(''.join(graphemes))
            bad_g = [g for g in graphemes if g not in valid_gset]
            if bad_g:
                print("Line {}: Invalid graphemes {}".format(line, bad_g))
                valid = False

            if valid:
                valid_row += 1
                p_count += len(phonemes)
                g_count += len(graphemes)
            else:
                invalid_row += 1
    except ValueError:
        pass

print("Valid rows: {}, Invalid rows: {}, p_count: {}, g_count: {}".format(
    valid_row, invalid_row, p_count, g_count))
```

Here's the output I got:

```
$ python test.py
Line 5: Number of phonemes and graphemes differ.
Line 6: Number of phonemes and graphemes differ.
Line 7: Invalid graphemes ['!']
Line 8: Invalid phonemes ['SX']
Valid rows: 3, Invalid rows: 4, p_count: 12, g_count: 16
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Valid_sets are supposed to be preset and I added above. The answer I was hoping for the validrow should be 4

Comment: I edited my code to account for the data you provided.

Comment: This is very close to what I have thought about. I have also edited on the condition saying that "ee" should be valid since "e" and "e" both are in the valid set. Same for "ay" and others like that. Thanks man sorry for bothering.

Comment: Are the graphemes just the input words as spelled? If so, you should probably join them together and then convert them back into a list.

Comment: I added this line `graphemes = list(''.join(graphemes))` to collapse the graphemes back into letters.

Comment: That is actually a very good way to do it. I will try that and see what happens. Thank you very much!